# mysql order by votes but newer post has more value

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, sql-order-by, vote

My table exists of **posts.id**, **vote** and **posttime** (when the posts was added). When displaying on page, I ORDER BY vote DESC. The thing is, I need to make new posts have more value than older post.

Meaning if:
post **A** was added **3rd April** and has **12** votes, 
post **B** was added **4th April** and has only **5** votes. 
Post B should be displayed higher than post A. Do you understand?

My query:

```
$query = "SELECT 
                posts.id, 
                rubrik, 
                link, 
                name, 
                userid, 
                posttime
              FROM `posts` 
              INNER JOIN `user` 
              ON posts.userid = user.id
              ORDER BY vote DESC";
```

Now, I need to do something with **posttime**, but I can't understand how.

I feel I was a bit unclear, still thanks for the answers.
What the final result would be, is that top voted posts that are 2 days old should make way for newer posts with a lot of votes but still lower than the old posts.

Does that make sense?

Comment: So basically you want to order by postdate and then by vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to order by posttime and then vote you can do this:

```
$query = "SELECT 
            posts.id, 
            rubrik, 
            link, 
            name, 
            userid, 
            posttime
          FROM `posts` 
          INNER JOIN `user` 
          ON posts.userid = user.id
          ORDER BY posttime, vote DESC";
```